# Jenkins on Mac: Cannot run program "pdepend"

Tags: macos, ant, jenkins, phpunit

Every time I try to run a build, I get a bunch of lines like this:

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/dghhtreew/workspace/build.xml:28:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/dghhtreew/workspace/build.xml:39: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pdepend": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Here's the relevant part from my build.xml, which was auto-generated by PHP Project Wizard:

```
...
 <target name="parallelTasks" description="Run the pdepend, phpmd, phpcpd, phpcs, phpdoc and phploc tasks in parallel using a maximum of 2 threads.">
  <parallel threadCount="2">
   <sequential>
    <antcall target="pdepend"/>
    <antcall target="phpmd"/>
   </sequential>
   <antcall target="phpcpd"/>
   <antcall target="phpcs"/>
   <antcall target="phpdoc"/>
   <antcall target="phploc"/>
  </parallel>
 </target>
 <target name="pdepend" description="Generate jdepend.xml and software metrics charts using PHP_Depend">
  <exec executable="pdepend">
   <arg line="--jdepend-xml=${basedir}/build/logs/jdepend.xml
              --jdepend-chart=${basedir}/build/pdepend/dependencies.svg
              --overview-pyramid=${basedir}/build/pdepend/overview-pyramid.svg
              ${source}" />
  </exec>
 </target>
...
```

Apparently the Jenkins user cannot find these commands or something. When I log in via the terminal to Jenkins like this:

```
sudo -s -H -u jenkins
```

and try `pdepend` it works as expected. But for some reason it won't work when executed from the Jenkins server. I tried setting absolute paths in the executable line, but I just got the same result. I haven't messed with the install or anything, I have the latest version (1.488) of Jenkins via the [mac installer](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

*Why can't jenkins do anything??*

Answer (score 2):

This is an execution path problem with the exec task. Try specifying the entire path to the pdepend command.

```
  <exec executable="/complete/path/to/command/pdepend">
  ..
```

## Update

If this still doesn't work check the permissions on the **pdepend** command to ensure that it's executable by the jenkins user.

It's also worth checking the return code when running the pdepend command directly:

```
sudo -u jenkins /complete/path/to/command/pdepend || echo non-zero return code
```

Comment: As stated above: "I tried setting absolute paths in the executable line, but I just got the same result."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have installed commands, so for me easiest way is via composer:

```
composer global require 'pdepend/pdepend=*'
```

If you don't have composer, install it:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

php composer.phar global require 'pdepend/pdepend=*'
```

Jenkins let's to ad path variables, you don't need to add paths

1. Please click "Manage Jenkins"
2. Click Configure System
3. Find checkbox "Environment variables" and make sure it is checked
4. Add new: 
   name: PATH
   value: $PATH:/Users/YOUR_USER/.composer/vendor/bin